# Updating Composite Primary Key EF 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table as below with composite primary keys

```
[Table("REQUEST_DATA")]
public class RequestData
{
    public RequestData()
    {
        RequestDataMapping = new HashSet<RequestDataMapping>();
    }
   
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId{ get; set; }
   
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    
    
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequestDataMapping> RequestDataMapping { get; set; }
}
```

I want to remove the column "UserId" and change the primary composite to just with RequestId column.

When I remove then from the EF class and generate the Migration script. I see a column deletion from RequestDataMapping table and an addition of column to my RequestData table.

I have not specified any mapping between the RequestDataMapping table and RequestData via fluentAPI as well.

I am using EF Code first apporoach.

Is there something that I am doing fundamentally wrong or is it not possible in EF?

Thanks

Comment: `I see a column deletion ... and an addition ...` Please include what you see in the question, perhaps using a 'before and after' scenario.

Comment: Hi Peter. The class I have given above is the current state of the EF class. I am removing only the Key property of CandidateId. 
After this when I generate the migration script. I see a column addition in the RequestData table  like this RequestData_RequestId as if it's creating a new primary key column

Comment: @PeterB this is what I have mentioned above
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REQUEST_DATA] ADD [Staff_RequestId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0